# Performance bottleneck with EclipsLink 2.0

Tags: jpa

Recently while I was using EclipsLink 2.0 I run into performance bottleneck problem with my implementation of  persisting  objects.

To be more specific I used to have the following implementation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS")
public class CustomerEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private volatile Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

private static final long  serialVersionUID = 6952530957072210017L;

private String custGroup;
private String address;
private String nameOfFirstPerson;
private String contactPerson;
private String phone;
private String fax;
private String email;
private String comments;
private String defaultCustomer;
private volatile boolean delayedPaymentAllowed;
private volatile long periodOfDelayedPaymentAllowed;
private volatile boolean restrictionsOnDelayedPayment;
private volatile double maxAmoutPemittedSom;
private volatile double maxAmoutPemittedYE;
private transient String salesPointName;

@Column(length=25483)
private HashMap<String, PriceItem> totalBalance;

@Column(length=25483)
private HashMap<String, PriceItem> totalBalanceUsd;

private transient boolean valueChanged = false;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier")
private Collection<PurchaseInvoiceEntity> purchaseInvoices;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")
private Collection<SalesInvoiceEntity> salesInvoices;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "payer")
private Collection<PayInSlipEntity> payInSlips;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipient")
private Collection<PaymentOrderEntity> paymentOrders;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipient")
private Collection<WriteOffEntity> writeOffs;

@ManyToOne()
private ResponsiblePersonForDebtEntity responsiblePersonForDebt;

@ManyToOne
private CustomerGroupEntity customerGroup;


public CustomerEntity() {

    valueChanged = false;
}
...
}
```

and while each time I was adding an instance of new document into appropriate Collection  while inserting a new instance of document into a table I detected that it takes too long to insert the document. I come across of this problem while I was using profiler module of netbeans ide 6.9. Actually I was using these collections in order to check for emptiness  with related documents.

Answer (score 0):

In order to tackle the problem I simply applied  the following solution:

1. I simply removed document references :

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier")
   private Collection purchaseInvoices;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")
   private Collection salesInvoices;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "payer")
   private Collection payInSlips;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipient")
   private Collection paymentOrders;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipient")
   private Collection writeOffs;

from the CusotmerEntity:

```
 @Entity
```

@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS")
public class CustomerEntity implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private volatile Long id;
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6952530957072210017L;
private String custGroup;
private String address;
private String nameOfFirstPerson;
private String contactPerson;
private String phone;
private String fax;
private String email;
private String comments;
private String defaultCustomer;
private volatile boolean delayedPaymentAllowed;
private volatile long periodOfDelayedPaymentAllowed;
private volatile boolean restrictionsOnDelayedPayment;
private volatile double maxAmoutPemittedSom;
private volatile double maxAmoutPemittedYE;
private transient String salesPointName;
@Column(length = 25483)
private HashMap<String, PriceItem> totalBalance;
@Column(length = 25483)
private HashMap<String, PriceItem> totalBalanceUsd;
private transient boolean valueChanged = false;
@ManyToOne()
private ResponsiblePersonForDebtEntity responsiblePersonForDebt;
@ManyToOne
private CustomerGroupEntity customerGroup;

public CustomerEntity() {

    valueChanged = false;
}
 .....}
```

1. while checking for references for the documents I used JPA query while editing or deleting CustomerEntity.

This simple change removed the most affecting performance problem.

Side Note:

Please while using performance profiler  include a check for package methods too(eclipslink for ex.)

Answer (score 0):

For performance and scalability  issues in JPA please read or listen S"Strategies and Best Practices for Highly Scalable Java Persistence Applications" by Gordon Yorke.